# Using `say` to create my own audiobooks

Tags: macos, applications, services, text-to-speech

I like the idea of being able to select a bunch of text and have it saved as an audio file and/or simply read back to me using OS X's default `say` functionality. It's almost like I can create my own instant personal audiobooks anytime I like. The problem is; the default voices, and more specifically, the robotic speech patterns, can get become quite unbearable to listen to. Is there a solution or an alternative available to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have You tried all the voices? In System Preferences -> Dictation & Speech there's a possibility to download additional voices. Some of them are not so "robotic".

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I have done, yeah. The problem is not so much the ***timbre or dialect***. It's more; the ***unnatural rhythm & inappropriate tone*** (or lack thereof) that make it difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

## Optional Voices in OS X

OS X includes support for numerous languages, take a look at the **Other Languages** section of [Speaking with a French accent – OS X say](http://theworklife.com/graham-miln/2015/09/04/speaking-with-a-french-accent-os-x-say/). The optional voices include alternative English speakers:

> To discover the full list of voices and associated languages:
>
> 1. Open **System Preferences.app**
> 2. Select **Dictation & Speech**
> 3. Select **System Voice > Customize…**

[image: Select voices in OS X]

## Customising Synthesised Speech

Apple's development documentation includes [Techniques for Customizing Synthesized Speech](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html). This is a technical document aimed at developers but it includes a section on [Use Embedded Speech Commands to Fine-Tune Spoken Output](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/SpeechOverview/SpeechOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH3-SW5) that offers a way to embed additional statements within your text that influence the synthesised voice.

## Cepstral: Buy Professional Voices

You can also purchase additional voices for use with OS X. Voices are available from [Cepstral](https://www.cereproc.com/products/Mac_OSX_voices):

> **CereVoice text-to-speech is available for Apple Mac OS X**, bringing CereProc's high-quality voices to computers running Apple's OS X: 10.5 Leopard, 10.6 Snow Leopard, 10.7 Lion, 10.8 Mountain Lion, 10.9 Mavericks, 10.10 Yosemite and 10.11 El Capitan (Intel Macs only). CereVoice can replace the default Mac voices with a wide range of other accents and languages.

Answer (score -1):

- Read Me a Book
- Tell Me A Story
- TextSpeech Pro for Mac OS X

And you can write own program:

- Use speak
- Use own voice, but so hard because need voice for all words and need some tones :)